# How do programmers take advantage of programming languages to make graphics?

Tags: graphics, gui

I was wondering for a pretty long time about graphics in all programming languages(no code available). Back in the rise of programming languages, such as C, Assembly, C++, and others, they had no graphics library (Assembly used raycaster, but still can fall under 3d graphics or at least the illusion that it is), so how were programmers able to manipulate the code into putting graphics on the screen (like Apple Lisa did). And, is code like that still available?

Comment: This sounds like a generic CS question, a less than well researched if I may add. Not sure what the retro part is supposed to be.

Comment: in the old MS-DOS and 8bit  days no gfx lib can't stop a decent programmer from rendering even 3D was not a problem ... we got direct pixel or VRAM access, low resolutions (meaning less CPU power and memory needed) ... for example even fully 3D depth buffered polygon engine with texture and lighting was no problem ... here [2D game in asm example for MS-DOS and 320x200x256c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29579522/2521214) and here a [B&W 3D and 2D engine for MCU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66507640/2521214) example (similar to old 8 bit stuff)

Comment: I am having a bit of a hard time parsing the English here. I am not sure what ‘Assembly used raycaster, but still can fall under 3d graphics or at least the illusion that it is’ is supposed to convey.

Comment: I think this question should be reopened because wanting to know how controlling graphics is even possible on a computer is a valid question, and the two answers given are a good start.

Comment: @Raffzahn This started on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/438111/how-do-programmers-take-advantage-of-programming-languages-to-make-graphics) and I think there's the core of a good question in here about the evolution of graphics rendering from the early days. [I did make it very, very clear (I thought) to the OP that they should not just copy and paste it here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/438111/how-do-programmers-take-advantage-of-programming-languages-to-make-graphics#comment961436_438111) but they have ignored me.

Comment: @PhilipKendall yes, that's **very** clear :)) The question is by very nature not an RC one. Basic CS/programming questions are by default off-topic on RC.SE. To be valid it would need to have a tie to RC hardware that is no longer present in modern computing (or maybe concepts, but those get easy disputed - as o concept is really ever gone). All of that aside the question is simply too unspecified, and any answer will be not based on the question but heavy interpretation thereof fuelled by opinion about what is asked. Possibly needing to include large chunks of TAOCP.

Comment: @knol It would be, if that is what the question is asking; as written, I don’t think it is sufficiently clear that it does. I would like to see that addressed before I vote to reopen.

Comment: The *computer* displays graphics. The programmer just stores the data for the graphics chips to read.

Comment: Are there videos about that kind of stuff, or would that go under OS theory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the IBM PC under DOS, using the original CGA card, one would typically invoke a routine in ROM to invoke graphics mode.  Once e.g. 640×200 black and white graphics mode was established, the display hardware would, about 60 times per second, fetch the contents of memory in the range `(char*)0xB8000000` to `(char*)0xB800004F` and feed it to a shift register while the monitor was drawing the first "visible" scan line, then fetch the contents of `(char*)0xB8002000` to `(char*)0xB800204F` and feed it to a shift register while the monitor was drawing the second line.  Then a lines starting at `(char*)0xB8000050`, `(char*)0xB8002050`, `(char*)0xB80000A0`, `(char*)0xB80020A0`, etc. until a total of 200 lines had been output.  The hardware would then wait until the start of the first visible line of the next frame and repeat the procedure.

If data are written via any means to the areas of memory that will be clocked out by the display controller, those bit patterns will appear on the display.  The C Standard doesn't specify the effect of writing to such addresses, but a typical C implementations for that platform, running on a machine with a CGA card, will process such actions "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment", i.e. change the bit patterns that will be displayed.

Later display controllers require more complicated sequences of actions to produce graphics, but the same principles still apply.  Until Windows, most programs would produce graphics by accessing display memory directly, since such approaches would often be much faster (more than an order of magnitude) than trying to use the routines in ROM to draw graphics.

On platforms like the Lisa or Macintosh, graphic routines in ROM were written to be sufficiently efficient that most programs for those platforms would use them rather than writing display memory directly.  Under Windows, programs would generally use routines that were built into Windows, which would in turn invoke device drivers supplied by display card vendors.  In the "olden days", however, writing directly to the display memory was *the* way to get good performance.

Comment: I know the author is too classy to enquire, but why has somebody given this post a negative rating? It seems to do a pretty good job of explaining where pixels come from and therefore how a program can manipulate them to me.

Comment: @Tommy There are some who feel that a question they believe is poor should not be answered by anyone.  I'm not one of them, nor am I convinced it's such a bad question, but that's one possible explanation.

Comment: @WayneConrad: The way graphics were handled in the 1980s is very different from the way they're usually handled today, so although there are some modern embedded systems that handle graphics using similar approaches, a lot of programmers would be unfamiliar with them, making them a fair retro topic.

Comment: @supercat That's still how things are done on many embedded systems (e.g. SPI or 8080/68000 bus LCD displays).  Typically one uses a graphics library to output to the display but often one will need to create the library oneself.

Comment: @AlexHajnal: I've written such libraries byself, both on retro and embedded systems.  They're similar to each other, but very far removed from modern desktop of mobile systems, and I think that as applied to desktop computers doing graphics in such a fashion is definitely "retro".

Comment: @supercat The only real difference from my perspective is that  nowadays C/C++ is typically the language used for writing the libraries whereas in the past assembly was used.  Compilers have gotten pretty good at generating fast/small machine code.  Agreed that bare-metal graphics programming (not just for libraries but as especially for games) is definitely retro.  Outside the embedded space writing directly to a display's memory is no longer done (it's usually not even possible from user-land).

Comment: @AlexHajnal: I wouldn't say so much that compilers have gotten better, but rather that architectures no longer include as many features that are more useful to an assembly language programmer than to a C compiler.  On the 8088, the 112 bits worth of general-purpose registers could be used as seven 16-bit registers, three 16-bit and eight 8-bit, or anything in between, which was very useful when coding in assembly language, but I don't think any compilers exploited that.

Comment: @AlexHajnal: More notably on the 8088, putting a data table in the code segment would make it possible to write assembly code that could have a loop do something like `temp = tileTable[offset1++]; screenData[offset2] = tileShapes[temp++]; screenData[offset2+80] = tileShape[temp++]; etc. without having to load any segment registers between tiles.  I was severely bummed when Turbo Pasal 4 removed the ability to easily put data in the code segment.

Answer (score 7):

Ultimately, it's all the same - there's code that manipulates hardware.

If there are no convenient libraries where someone else has written that code, you write it yourself.

For systems with (monochrome) bitmapped displays, you set a bit in video memory to '1' or '0', which either lights up the pixel, or it doesn't. Repeat for every pixel in the display.

Colour systems are similar, except that there's more than one bit per pixel.

(This answer is applicable to all programming - if you can't find one off-the-shelf, then you code it).

Comment: The meaning of "code that manipulates hardware" might be the question the asker is getting at. Really, only hardware can manipulate hardware.

Comment: The hardware I have in mind is that hardware involved in the execution of "store word in memory".